# Inserting Columns Not Working as Expected

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I am trying to insert some columns right after "Z" column With the Z column format but it ens up inserting the columns in the wrong part(second picture):

[image: First Picture]

[image: Second Picture]

This is the code I am working with: `

```
        For i = 1 To Quantity - 1

            Columns("Z:Z").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        Next`
```

The Value of Quantity is given by the user in a textbox. 
Can anyone help me?
thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.  What is this `Z column format` that you are trying to replicate?  What was entered in the text box that resulted in your code producing the second picture from the first?  What to you expect to happen -- a screen shot or table of your expected results would be useful.

Comment: I am trying to replicate the entire Z column and inserting it with the same width to the right, and the code what is doing is inserting columns in the W column with the W width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
For i = 1 To quantity - 1

    Columns("Z:Z").Select
    ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1).Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

Next
```

Offset will Insert the column to the right
Excel normally insert the column to the left of the selection.
With your code you can use:

```
For i = 1 To Quantity - 1

            Columns("AA:AA").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

i tried your code and it does exactly what you want it to do

there is a possibility that some other code is running and not this code

resize your window so that you can see the worksheet

then singlestep the following code by pressing F8 key

your code can be rewritten as below:

note: you do not need to "select" the Z column to perform actions on it

---

```
Sub Macro1()
    For i = 1 To 5
        Columns("Z:Z").Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next
End Sub


' you can also do multiples of columns with one command


Sub Macro1()

    Quantity = 3

    ' insert multiple columns
    Range("z:z").Range(Columns(1), Columns(Quantity)).Select  ' multi column range anchored at column "Z"
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' or this way on one line without selecting
    Range("z:z").Range(Columns(1), Columns(Quantity)).Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' or this way
    Range("z:z").Range(Columns(1), Columns(Quantity)).Insert _
        Shift:=xlToRight, _
        CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

    ' or this way
    With Range("z:z").Range(Columns(1), Columns(Quantity))
        .Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    End With

End Sub
```

hope it helps